# Getting error while deploying angular app to heroku and while running ng serve?

Tags: angular, heroku

getting error "The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found."

Below is my package.json.

```
{
"name": "demo-deploy",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "node server.js",
"build": "ng build --prod",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e",
"postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/cli": "^7.2.3",
"@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.11",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"express": "^4.16.4",
"path": "^0.12.7",
"rxjs": "^5.5.6",
"typescript": "~2.5.3",
"zone.js": "^0.8.19"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "^7.2.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.11",
"@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"@types/node": "~6.0.60",
"codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
"enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~2.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.1.2",
"ts-node": "~4.1.0",
"tslint": "~5.9.1",
"typescript": "~2.5.3"
},
"engines": {
"node": "8.9.4",
"npm": "5.6.0"
}
}
```

and server.js

```
//Install express server
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express(); 
// Serve only the static files form the dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/'));
app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dist/index.html'));
});
  // Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

the server.js file is in root directory.
I followed this post to deploy a dummy app to heroku
https://medium.com/@hellotunmbi/how-to-deploy-angular-application-to-heroku-1d56e09c5147

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your project doesn't have `angular.json` file present in your folder.

The post covered deployment for `"@angular/cli": "^1.4.9"` which is old and used to generate `angular-cli.json` file, which is not used anymore.

If you want to migrate from old angular-cli version to new one, then you can run the following command:

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.4.9
```

where `--from` refers to your current version of angular-cli. Doing so, will take care of all the conversion and necessary files.

**Reference:** https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12215#issuecomment-433593036

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. the problem is solved but the deployment still failed.
Error : > ng build --aot -prod
       
       Unknown option: '-d'
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno 1
       npm ERR! demo-deploy@0.0.0 postinstall: `ng build --aot -prod`
       npm ERR! Exit status 1
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Failed at the demo-deploy@0.0.0 postinstall script.
       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: @ShaileshTanwar This error is shown because you have used 1 `-` instead of 2. Run command like this, `ng build --aot --prod`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was exclusively after deploying to Heroku. My app built fine everywhere else.

Just remove `build` command from `package.json`. Or if you actually do want it to build remotely then modify to be more accurate.